# error: #error user defined BOOST_POSIX_API or BOOST_WINDOWS_API not supported

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to compile a program and getting the error in the title. The compilation requires boost. The boost 1.55 is installed and I don't think there is problem with the boost. I don't have any idea why I am getting this error.

My machine is running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and gcc version is 4.8.4.

Comment: Boost is a C++ library. Removing your C tag and adding C++. Removing your "cananyonehelp" phrase (contains no information). Asking you to supply more information, such as a minimal verifiable example, your compiler command line etc.

Comment: It almost sounds like a version mismatch; e.g. your environment is misconfigured in a way that it's pulling header files from two different versions of boost.